# ACF acf_add_local_field_group doesn't recognized array variable for fields attribute value in php

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I have a generated tabs for the custom post type taxonomy, inside the function I got a  **acf_add_local_field_group** and a loop to filer taxonomy so I can change the fields value dynamically.

Here is the logic format of my code:

```
   $field = array();
   FOREACH LOOP

     $field[] = array(
           'key' => '1234',
           'label' => $dynamic_label,
           'name' => 'some_name',
           'type' => 'tab',
           'parent' => 'tab_group_23',
     );

   ENDFOREACH
```

And here is my **acf_add_local_field_group** function: **THIS IS NOT WORKING** though $fields value and format is the same when hardcoded.

```
   acf_add_local_field_group(array(
        'key' => 'tab_group_23',
        'title' => 'Product Sizes and Prices',
        'name' => 'group_sizes_tab',
        'fields' =>$field,            // <------------ NOT WORKING WHEN I USE THIS
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'products',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

Just to make it clear if I tried to hardcode the **$fields** value it'll work just fine like so:

**THIS IS WORKING**

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'tab_group_23',
    'title' => 'Product Sizes and Prices',
    'name' => 'group_sizes_tab',
    'fields' =>array(
      array(
       'key' => '1234',
       'label' => $dynamic_label,
       'name' => 'some_name',
       'type' => 'tab',
       'parent' => 'tab_group_23',
      )
     ),
    'location' => array (
        array (
            array (
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'products',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

So my question is how can I make it work using my variable `$field`?

Comment: have you dumped `$field` to check whats actually in it?

Comment: @Ashley Brown, yes, it gives me my expected output. Like I said the format and values are the same with the one that is hardcoded.

Comment: store the array you put into the function and dump that instead just before calling the function. Something has to be up with the input if hardcoding works fine

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Sorry I'm confused. I declared my $field =array(); inside my function. Sorry to confused you as well, i'll update my question

Comment: You call your function like `acf_add_local_field_group(array(...` right? You see that raw array `..group(array(... <---` ? Store that in a variable and then put the variable in the function e.g. `..group($array)` But dump that array before calling the function see everything as a whole from a variable before calling it - this will allow us to see the entire data passed in as a whole & to *double* check the formatting is correct

Comment: @AshleyBrown Here is the value of $fields array http://codejaw.com/lica3a and this is the value of $arrays http://codejaw.com/wozosi I don't see the difference. It's working fine when $arrays is set. If you want to see the code you can look here http://codejaw.com/tepezi